# Is there a better, more optimized way to perform this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query where we are selecting a list of products but also need to query an orders table to find how many have been sold.  Is there a more efficient way to retrieve the numberSold sum without a subQuery?

```
SELECT tProducts.ID as ID,
tProducts.Name,
tProducts.Description,
Highlights=Replace(Replace(tProducts.Highlights, '##productdeliverydate##', convert(varchar, @ProjectReleaseDt, 101)),'##productltdedition##', @productltdedition),
tProducts.isLocked as isLocked,
tProducts.isVisible as isVisible,
tProducts.ImageID as ImageID,
tProducts.ShippingYN as ShippingYN,
tProducts.LastDateUpdate as LastDateUpdate,
tProducts.BaseUnitPrice as Price,
    FileExtension = case  tProjectImages.FileExtention
    WHEN tProjectImages.FileExtention then tProjectImages.FileExtention
    ELSE '.none'
    END,
    @ImagePath as ImagePath,
    @ImageServerPath  as ExternalServerPath,
    @ThumbExt as ThumbnailExtension,    
    tProducts.SalesContainerTypeID,
    tProducts.ListOrder,
    tProducts.isParticipantListed,
    tProducts.LimitQuantity,
    tPRoducts.isFeature,
    numbersold=(SELECT sum(quantity) 
                  from tOrderDetails 
                  JOIN tOrders 
                    on tORders.OrderID=tORderDetails.ORderID 
                 where productID=tProducts.ID 
                   and tOrders.isTestOrder=0),
FROM tProducts
LEFT JOIN tProjectImages ON tProducts.ImageID = tProjectImages.ID
WHERE tProducts.ProjectID = @projectID  
and tProducts.isVisible=1 
and tProducts.SalesContainerTypeID = 6 
and tProducts.langID=@langID
ORDER BY tProducts.BaseUnitPrice ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having performance problems, then perhaps indexes would help.

The best indexes for the subquery are:  `tOrderDetails(productid, orderid, quantity)` and `tOrder(orderid, isTestOrder)`.

The best indexes for the outer query are:  `tProducts(ProjectId, isVisibleId, SalesContainerTypeID, langID, BaseUnitPrice, ImageID)` and `tProjectImages(Id)`.

Comment: Marked as answer.  The suggested indexes were in fact the best solution and the original subquery seems to be the most optimal

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it would be more efficient (you'd want to check the execution plan).  But here's an alternative version with an `outer join` to a subquery:

```
SELECT ...
    numbersold=t.qty,
FROM tProducts
    LEFT JOIN tProjectImages ON tProducts.ImageID = tProjectImages.ID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT sum(quantity) qty,  productID
        FROM tOrderDetails 
            JOIN tOrders on tORders.OrderID =tORderDetails.ORderID 
        GROUP BY productID
    ) t ON t.productID=tProducts.ID and tOrders.isTestOrder=0
WHERE tProducts.ProjectID = @projectID and 
     tProducts.isVisible=1 and 
     tProducts.SalesContainerTypeID = 6 and 
     tProducts.langID=@langID
ORDER BY tProducts.BaseUnitPrice ASC
```

Comment: The original query is probably more efficient.  This query is aggregating all the order details and orders.  The outer query is probably restricting the data to just a few orders, based on all the restrictions in the `where` clause.  The correlated subquery only does the calculations that are necessary.

Comment: @sgeddes - Thanks I will give it a try.   Gordon - Unfortunately it probably is.  I have an aversion to subqueries :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- Thanks for the information.  I wasn't sure, but wondered if the `outer join / subquery` would only execute once, where the correlated subquery would execute for each match.  Nice to know.  As with all performance issues, I generally review the execution plan and move forward accordingly.  Thanks again.

Comment: @sgeddes . . . It is always worth checking.  However, the assumption that correlated subqueries are bad is wrong.  Sometimes bad.  Sometimes good.  This happens to be a case where they may provide the best performance (assuming the right indexes are in place), because of the heavy filtering in the outer query.